# How to connect boost / network / uri

Tags: c, boost

Please tell me how to connect  in the project
I needed a library for parsing with a URL. Found such a solution: https://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/in_depth/uri.html. Downloaded cpp-netlib-0.9.4. But I don’t know how to connect with my project

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/network/uri.hpp>
#include <boost/network/uri/uri_io.hpp>
using namespace boost::network;
int main() {
    uri::uri url;
    url << uri::scheme("http")
        << uri::host("www.github.com")
        << uri::path("/cpp-netlib");
    std::cout << url << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "connect" and "my project". I have a feeling you're learning about linking a third-party library, but we don't know what tools you're using so we can't really say more than is likely already in the docs for that library (eg https://cpp-netlib.org/0.13.0/getting_started.html#using-cpp-netlib)